How to append custom component as element in Angular directive?
I have a directive that's supposed to add an icon to the targeted element. It works today by setting the innerHTML to SVG as a string. Now, I'd like to improve it, so I declared a custom component that encapsulates the icon.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-icon',
  template:'<svg ...><path ... /></svg>' ...]
})
export class IconComponent {}

The problem is that the custom component won't render. A default component will, though, so I sense that my setup is correct.
@Directive({ selector: '[appSortable]' })
export class SortableDirective {

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.target = element.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
  }

  @HostListener("mouseenter")
  onMouseEnter() {
    const mark1 = this.renderer.createElement("app-icon-sort-asc");
    const mark2 = this.renderer.createElement("button");
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.target, mark1);
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.target, mark2);
  }
}

I've googled it a few times now but I'm confused: there's no "single strategy", different blogs discuss it from different angles. Also, quite a few resources are based on factory resolver, which is deprecated. I'm on Angular 16 and I can't determine which way to focus. I ahven't found out-of-the-box solution so I'll need to assemble one myself based on docs and other resources. However, since those are quite heterogenious, I get stuck in uncertainty.

Do I need to convert my icon component into web component?
Do I need to follow the is attributation?
Do I need to apply createCustomElement somehow?


use ViewContainerRef to .createComponent. that simple

@Andrei Would you like to elaborate a bit, please? Is that yes/no to any of the 3 considerations?

createCustomElement is part of @angular/elements. and angular elements is a library to help wrapping components into web components. if you are using angular components inside of angular application angular/elements doesn't make any sense. so the answer is no, no, no. angular/elements can be useful to reuse components written in angular in frameworkless envrironment or just in other framework application

@Andrei Sorry, I feel confused. Are you suggesting that I should not utilize Renderer2? I sense that you're suggesting changing the injected ElementRef and instead inject ViewContainerRef. Am I getting you correctly?

yes. that sounds right. refering native html elements is rather a rare thing that anyone should do. vast majority of use cases can be solved by angular apis
